Using field alias from main query in a subquery
I want to filter in subquery with aliased field from main query:
select a.created_at::date as creation_date, a.column as col1, 
       (select count(*)
        from table b
        where a.col1 = b.col1
          and a.created_at::date = b.created_at::date) as count_one 
from table a
group by creation_date, col1;

but this gives error
ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "a.created_at" from outer query
Any options how to solve it?

Why the GROUP BY? (I see no aggregate functions.)

Column created_at data type?

BTW, note that tables have columns, not fields.

What happens if you try group by a.created_at::date, field;

@jarlh fixed the statement, created_at is a timestamp

@Charlieface nothing, the problem is that I can't reference outer query column inside subquery

You see the problem when looking at the query: In the subquery you try to access a.col1, but there is no col1 in table a; you would have to access the original name a.column, because the alias does not yet exist. (The expressions in the select clause can be executed in arbitrary order, so the DBMS can execute a.column as col1 before or after the subquery; hence the alias name cannot be used in the subquery.  a.created_at on the other hand has ceased to exist when you run the subquery, because at that point you have already aggregated all a.created_at to a.created_at::date.

The solution is hence to get the distinct date/col1 pairs before executing the subquery. This is done with an ad-hoc view (FROM (...) ax or WITH ax AS (...)). My answer shows how.

I don't know the actual column types, but I do see the outer query casts the original created_at as a date, and then gives it a creation_date alias. Assuming this was originally a datetime (or similar), this means we have narrowed the range of the values from the source column.
The outer query then does a GROUP BY using the alias for the narrowed column, meaning the GROUP BY MUST be grouping to the result of the cast, rather than with the source of the cast.
Now we look at the inner/nested query, and see it's trying to reference the original source column. But because of the GROUP BY in the outer query, this column no longer exists.
The database has to resolve the groupings before it can resolve correlated subqueries. I know you're trying to do the same cast, to get the same values, but for this it does not matter... from the perspective of the subquery, the original source column is no longer there.

thanks for explanation, but is it possible to solve with other query?

You may just be able to use the alias in the nested query.

It's unclear why this doesn't work, because you are using the same value in the subquery as the group by. At the very least, it should work if you don't use the alias and instead repeat the calculation group by a.created_at::date, a.column.
Otherwise, you could use a lateral join for the group by value
select
  v.creation_date,
  a.column as col1, 
  (
    select count(*)
    from table b
    where a."column" = b.col1
      and v.creation_date = b.created_at::date
  ) as count_one 
from table a
cross join lateral (values
  (a.created_at::date)
) v(creation_date)
group by
  v.creation_date,
  a."column";

Note that casting in a where can be inefficient. You might be better off with
      and b.created_at >= v.creation_date
      and b.created_at <  v.creation_date + interval '1' day


You want distinct col1 / date pairs from table a. Then, for each such pair you want the count of table b rows.
These are two steps. Do step 1 first, then do step 2. For instance:
select 
  ax.creation_date,
  ax.col1, 
  (
     select count(*)
     from table b
     where b.col1 = ax.col1
     and b.created_at::date = ax.creation_date
  ) as count_one 
from (select distinct created_at::date as creation_date, column as col1 from a) ax
order by ax.creation_date, ax.col1;

